# Disable CSS transition delay

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying to disable the transition delay by adding a class that put the value of the delay to 0 seconds.

I don't now why it doesn't work.

The only thing that worked for me was to add the `.no-anim` class `transition: none;` but than there is no animation at all.

I want to keep the animation also after clicking the button that add the class so the solution with the `transition: none;` is not good enough in my case...

Any idea?

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
 $this = $('.box');
 $this.addClass('no-anim');
  setTimeout(function() {
   $this.removeClass('no-anim');
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #333;
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;  
}

.box:hover {
    width: 300px;
    transition-delay: 2.5s;
  }
  .box.no-anim {
    transition-delay: .3s;
  }

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 30px;
    background: #ff3434;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="box">
  <span class="button"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector `.box.no-anim` has the same precedence as a plain `.box` selector (they're both just classes). That means that `.box.no-anim`'s addition of the `:hover` pseduo-selector is giving it a higher precendence, making it override your `no-anim` transition-delay.

Add `:hover` to your `.no-anim` selector as well and it will work correctly.

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
 $this = $('.box');
 $this.addClass('no-anim');
  setTimeout(function() {
   $this.removeClass('no-anim');
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #333;
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;  
}

.box:hover {
    width: 300px;
    transition-delay: 2.5s;
  }
  .box.no-anim:hover {
    transition-delay: .3s;
  }

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 30px;
    background: #ff3434;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="box">
  <span class="button"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't see it work on Chrome 51. I also tried this solution myself here https://jsfiddle.net/6qk5tmv3/ Is it working for you?

Comment: @MatanG. Did you try it in the code snippet? It works fine there. There's something screwed up in your fiddle, but it [works fine here...](https://jsfiddle.net/6qk5tmv3/3/)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I still can't see it working. If I click on the red button while the box have no `.no-anim` class on it the delay stay the same (2.5 seconds) and not 0.3 seconds like I set in the `.box.no-anim:hover`...